# laravel undifined variable in foreach loop

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i am trying to send an object to a view and it says its undefined this is my controller and i have included `use App\Drug`

```
public function index()
{
    $drugs = Drug::all();
    return view('signup7')->withDrugs($drugs);
}
```

and this is my view

```
@foreach ($drugs as $drug)
    <h5>Name : {{ $drug->generic_name}}</h5>
    <h5>Ctegory : {{ $drug->dieases_category_id}}</h5>
    <h5>Price: {{ $drug->sell_price}}</h5>
@endforeach
```

this is my route

```
Route::get('/medication/search', 'DrugsController@index')->name('drug.index');
```

Comment: Change to `return view('signup7')->with('drugs', $drugs);`

Comment: @sta that code does not work either

Comment: make sure you are using the correct view as all of the below method should work:
1. return view('signup7')->with('drugs', $drugs);
2. return view('signup7',['drugs'=>$drugs]);
3. return view('signup7', compact('drugs'));


Also, try to print `drugs` in view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function index()
{
    $drugs = Drug::all();
    return view('signup7',['drugs'=>$drugs]);
}
```

This is a method according to the official documentation of Laravel 7. When passing information in this manner, the data should be an array with key / value pairs. Inside your view, you can then access each value using its corresponding key.
You can also pass data using the with() method :

```
return view('signup7')->with('drugs',$drugs);
```

Answer (score 0):

this code might work

```
public function index()
{
    $drugs = Drug::all();
    return view('signup7', compact('drugs'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below it will work.

```
public function methodName(){
   $drugs = Drug::all();
   return view('signup7', compact('drugs'));
}
```